# Merge Replication vs Updating master server and transactional repl back

Tags: sql-server

The company I work for has two different SQL servers.  One is our primary production servers, while another one is basically a copy of a few of the tables and that server is used for things like our accounts web site. Changes occur on second server, then are synched to the primary server via merge replication, which then synchs to all the other subscribers which are used for other things.  These other subscribers don't have to use merge replication as they only read the data and don't update it, but that's what we use for now.

My question is: Does anyone know what the performance impact of this type of topology is?  I'm looking at doing one of two things and want to know what sort of performance I'll receive from this.

1) Change it all to transaction replication.  Then the accounts web site would just update the primary server and then replicate stuff back down.  The downside would be that the web site would not show changes for a few minutes, but I think the performance (and management) of the replication might make this acceptable.

2) Change it so the primary and second server use merge, but I use transaction replication for everything else.  I know that transaction replication is less load on the server than merge, but I haven't seen anything on using both merge and transaction on the same table.  Realistically I'm thinking the only benefit to this is the management of it all.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution depends on what the 'other' servers need to do and how up to date they must be. Let me explain.

For any multiple server data infrastructure you have these options:

- Replication
- Log shipping
- Database mirroring

Replication is the best approach between your Primary server and your Accounts server.
If you have the bandwith (or even better, both servers sitting on a LAN), I suggest you use Transactional replication. This will keep it up to date and close to realtime on both servers and performance will not be affected too much if you have fast connections between the servers. (P.S. You can in the same approach look at using your secondary server as a warm standby device for the tables you are replicating, but this is only usefull to recover those spesific tables.)

For all your other servers (Seems asif they are mainly used for reporting?), I would suggest minimizing the effects of performance on the Primary server. To do this you might look at using Log Shipping or Database Mirroring in High Performance Mode.

- Log shipping can be setup to ship your logs only in the evenings reducing network traffic in online-time.
- Database mirroring in High Performance mode will ship your transactions async and will also help reduce traffic volumes (Based on log shipping)

NOTE: Both of these approaches will mean you can ONLY read from the databases on the 'other' servers. No inserts or updates. Depending on the chosen implimentation, your 'other' servers might also be behind the Primary Server in terms of updates by a couple of minutes to a couple of hours.

Hope this helps.